# Drop rows on condition in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove rows which contains "True" in the column "aff".

Expected result : Wikipedia.org raw (line) is removed

My csv:

```
website;aff;cond;ger;azs
wikipedia.org;True;False;False;True
youtube.com;False;False;False;False
amazon.es;False;False;False;False
```

My code:

```
check = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path2, "my.csv"), sep=";")
output = output.merge(check, on=["Domain"], how="left") 
output = output.loc[~(output["aff"] == "True")].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Print of output gives:

```
Domain            aff          cond      ger         azs
wikipedia.org     True         False     False       True
youtube.com       False        False     False       False
amazon.es         False        False     False       False
```

Print of output["aff"] gives:

```
0            True
1            False
2            False
3            False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you're looking for?

```
>>> !cat test.csv
website;aff;cond;ger;azs
wikipedia.org;True;False;False;True
youtube.com;False;False;False;False
amazon.es;False;False;False;False

>>> df=pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=';')

>>> df

         website    aff   cond    ger    azs
0  wikipedia.org   True  False  False   True
1    youtube.com  False  False  False  False
2      amazon.es  False  False  False  False


>>> df[~df['aff']]

       website    aff   cond    ger    azs
1  youtube.com  False  False  False  False
2    amazon.es  False  False  False  False
```

I am only guessing here as there is no desired output posted, but based on your explanation - this should do it for you.

Comment: Thx but it didn't help. I don't understand what's wrong with my code

Comment: can you elaborate please? Is that above not the desired output?If so - what is it?

Comment: Yes it is, but it's not working in my case

Comment: I succeed make it work only if it's a numerical value

Comment: I have amended my answer. This is literally all you need.

Answer (score 1):

You put the Boolean value in quotations so it is comparing your values to a string, not the True value. Your method works without the quotes. In fact, it works without comparing the 'aff' series to a True value since you're working with booleans.

Comment: Thank, I've just realized that